# Transparent Divider in SplitPane

Tags: javafx

Is there any way to make the Divider in a split pane transparent?

I have tried the following approach

```
.split-pane *.split-pane-divider {
-fx-padding: 0 1 0 1;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Also, I would rather do it from the java code, if it's possible.

```
splitPane.setStyle("");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With CSS:

```
.split-pane:horizontal > .split-pane-divider {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.split-pane:vertical > .split-pane-divider {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

By code, you need to find the divider and apply the style to it. Since there's no API for that, one easy way is with a lookup, after the stage is shown:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {    
    SplitPane split = new SplitPane();
    ...
    Scene scene = new Scene(split);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    Node divider = split.lookup(".split-pane-divider");
    if(divider!=null){
        divider.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you're actually trying to do,

```
.split-pane-divider {
  -fx-padding: 0 ;
}
```

might work.

Why would you want to make the divider transparent? It makes it virtually impossible for the user to resize the portions of the pane.

Comment: only solution that worked for me. Setting the background color to transparent was not working.