# Alternative to SplitPane for dividing "content", plus TitlePane collapse/expand problem; what should I use instead?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Matching portion of the FXML:

```
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL">
        <TreeView fx:id="parseTree" editable="false"/>
        <TitledPane collapsible="true" text="Node information">
            <TextArea fx:id="parseNodeDetails" editable="false"
                style="-fx-font-family: monospace"/>
        </TitledPane>
    </SplitPane>
```

Here is the current layout I have:

[image]

Now, the first problem is when I collapse then expand the `TitlePane`. Starting from the situation above, it gives this:

[image]

What I'd like to is that it expanded up to the size it took before (in fact, the maximum place allowed by the `SplitPane`. Is there a possibility to do this?

Another problem I have is that a `SplitPane`'s dividers are apparently not "hidable"; I have seen solutions using CSS ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27318146/1093528) for instance) but it looks a bit ugly... If I were to replace the `SplitPane` with something else, but still have the size constraint on the `TitlePane` expansion, what should I use?

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671094/change-growth-ratios-for-panes-inside-splitpane/27675244#27675244 ?

Comment: @eckig no, I haven't, but this looks interesting... Keeping the link, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this using a BorderPane: put the TreeView in the center and the TitledPane in the bottom.

Alternatively you could also try putting the TreeView and the TitledPane in a VBox. Set VBox.setVgrow( tree, Priority.ALWAYS );